# mongodb schema how to set default value for array of sub documents?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose-schema

Example I have this schema.

```
{
  field1: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  field2: [{
    subField1: {
      type: String,
    },
    subField2: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    }
  }]
}
```

How should I set the default value on the schema for the `field2` if I just provided the `field1` on the document insert?

example If i just insert `{field1: "sample string data"}`, then the value on the `field2` is an empty array.

Comment: You can user the schema.pre function to deal with such situation.
refer this - http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

can you try this?, use `type` to specify the schema and `default` for default values

```
const TesterSchema = new Schema({  
      field1: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
      },
      field2: {
        type : [{
          subField1: {
            type: String                  
          },
          subField2: {
            type: Number                  
          }
      }],
      default :[{subField2 : '0'}]
    }
  }
);
```

example

```
Tester.create({field1 : 'testing'}, function(err,doc){
    if(err) console.log(err)
    console.log(doc)
})
```

console output

```
Mongoose: testerzz.insert({ field1: 'testing', _id: ObjectId("5a6ae40a351d4254c6e0fdc2"), field2: [ { subField2: 0, _id: ObjectId("5a6ae40a351d4254c6e0fdc1") } ], __v: 0 })
{ __v: 0,
  field1: 'testing',
  _id: 5a6ae40a351d4254c6e0fdc2,
  field2: [ { subField2: 0, _id: 5a6ae40a351d4254c6e0fdc1 } ] }
```

mongo CLI

```
> db.testerzz.find({_id: ObjectId("5a6ae40a351d4254c6e0fdc2")}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a6ae40a351d4254c6e0fdc2"),
    "field1" : "testing",
    "field2" : [
        {
            "subField2" : 0,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a6ae40a351d4254c6e0fdc1")
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
>
```